# Trigger Azure DevOps pipeline with custom parameters

Tags: azure-devops

I have an Azure DevOps pipeline which runs npm run based on some runtime parameters.

Is there a possibility to trigger for example 3 jobs in the same pipeline, each of the job with different runtime parameters?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a possibility to trigger for example 3 jobs in the same pipeline, each of the job with different runtime parameters?

Yes. You can define the object type parameter and use each expression to iterate over the values.

Here is an example:

```
parameters:
- name: tests
  type: object
  default: [test1,test2,test3] 



jobs:
- ${{ each test in parameters.tests }}:
  - job: 
    steps:
      - script: echo ${{ test }}
```

**Result:**

[image]

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [Loop through parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script#loop-through-parameters)